Trouble retrieving specific data from Wikidata using SPARQL
I'm trying to retrieve specific data from Wikidata using SPARQL, but I'm encountering difficulties. Specifically, I'm attempting to extract the runway length for a particular airport entity (Q29863) from Wikidata. I've tried several SPARQL queries, but I haven't been successful in retrieving the desired information.
Here's one of the queries I've tried:
SELECT ?runwayLength ?runwayLengthLabel
WHERE {
  wd:Q29863 wdt:P869 ?runwayLength.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

However, this query doesn't return any results, even though I can see the runway length information is available on the Wikidata page for the airport (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q29863).
I've also attempted other variations of the query, but none seem to work. Can someone please assist me in crafting a SPARQL query that successfully retrieves the runway length for the specified airport from Wikidata?

P869 doesn't appear to exist and looking at that page for Q29863, length (P2043) is an attribute (ie qualifier in Wikidata-speak) of the runway (P529), not of the airport, so you'll need to adjust your query to retrieve the value for the qualifier.

from where do you have the property wdt:P869 ? If you look at your example entity, you can see that the runway property is P529 - moreover, the length (P2043) of the runway is attached to the runway as a statement qualifier.

A query would look like SELECT ?runwayLength ?runwayLengthLabel WHERE {   wd:Q29863 p:P529 ?runwayStmt .   ?runwayStmt pq:P2043 ?runwayLength        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } }

or a bit more compact if you don't need the statement node, you can use a propery path notation for the sequence of paths via / char: SELECT ?runwayLength ?runwayLengthLabel  {   wd:Q29863 p:P529/pq:P2043 ?runwayLength        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } }

That worked perfectly! Thank you. Is it possible to expand this for all runways in Sweden?

Property P869 does not exist anymore on Wikidata (since 2013!). Instead, as you can see from item Q29863, you should look for the usage of property P529 along with the qualifier P2043.
The following query by UninformedUser does the job:
SELECT ?runwayLength ?runwayLengthLabel {
  wd:Q29863 p:P529/pq:P2043 ?runwayLength
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

where p:P529 links the item (subject) and the P529-statement (object), whereas pq:P2043 links the P529-statement (subject) with the runway length (object).
If you want to extend to all the runways in Sweden, you can use the following query:
SELECT ?airport ?airportLabel ?runwayLength ?runwayLengthLabel {
  ?airport wdt:P17 wd:Q34;
           p:P529/pq:P2043 ?runwayLength
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

